# Set a const char pointer in a struct

Tags: c, string, struct, valgrind

I'm attempting to write a program where I can create tokens such that each token has a constant type and value.

token.h:

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H
typedef struct{
    const char *type;
    const char *value;
}token;

token *gen_token(const char *r, const char *val);

#endif
```

token.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lib/token.h"

token *gen_token(const char *type, const char *val){
    token o = {type, val}, *out = &o;
    return out;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lib/token.h"

int main(int argi, char *argv[]){
    const char th[] = "line", va[] = ":";

    token *t = gen_token(th, va);

    printf("(%s, %s)\n", t->type, t->value);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this normally, no errors seem to occur, but when valgrind takes a look at it, it complains alot. Here is my log:

```
==4086== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4086== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4086== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4086== Command: ./a lol
==4086== 
==4086== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4086==    at 0x4E7FD4F: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4086==    at 0x4C2EBE2: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:458)
==4086==    by 0x4E80D77: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4086==    at 0x4C2EBF4: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:458)
==4086==    by 0x4E80D77: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4086==    at 0x4EAAEEB: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1307)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4086==    at 0x4EAAEF1: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1309)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4086==    at 0x4EAAF03: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1307)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4086==    at 0x4EAAF0D: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1309)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4086==    at 0x4C32EB3: is_overlap (vg_replace_strmem.c:137)
==4086==    by 0x4C32EB3: __GI_mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1525)
==4086==    by 0x4EAAE23: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1327)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4086==    at 0x4C32EB9: is_overlap (vg_replace_strmem.c:140)
==4086==    by 0x4C32EB9: __GI_mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1525)
==4086==    by 0x4EAAE23: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1327)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4086==    at 0x4C32EC7: __GI_mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1525)
==4086==    by 0x4EAAE23: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1327)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4086==    at 0x4C32ECC: __GI_mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1525)
==4086==    by 0x4EAAE23: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1327)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4086==    at 0x4C32F64: __GI_mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1525)
==4086==    by 0x4EAAE23: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1327)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4086==    at 0x4C32F70: __GI_mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1525)
==4086==    by 0x4EAAE23: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1327)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086== 
==4086== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4086==    at 0x4C32F7E: __GI_mempcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1525)
==4086==    by 0x4EAAE23: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1327)
==4086==    by 0x4E80BBA: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==4086==    by 0x4E871F8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4086==    by 0x1087AB: main (main.c:11)
==4086==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4086==    at 0x108785: main (main.c:10)
==4086==  (line, :)
==4086== 
==4086== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4086==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4086==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==4086== 
==4086== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4086== 
==4086== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4086== ERROR SUMMARY: 36 errors from 14 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I'd much appreciate any help and/or critique on my code.

Comment: What is `out`? Don't return pointers to local variables.

Comment: `token o` is local auto variable. This is invalid outside the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function

```
token *gen_token(const char *type, const char *val){
    token o = {type, val}, *out = &o;
    return out;
}
```

Variable `out` point to the local variable `o`, which is disposed after function returns. This is pure accident you can read those values after you calling a function. Hence a warning about

> Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation

Instead you need to allocate memory and copy values into it. **NOTE** you need to remember to free allocated memory before exiting you program, especially if you'd like to make valgrind happy :)

Comment: So i should create the token in main and pass a pointer to my gen_token func?

Comment: No, you can create a token inside the function, but you just need to allocate memory for it on heap, out = malloc(sizeof(toke))... and then copy into struct fields values, e.g. out->value = malloc(strlen(value)); strcpy(out->value, value), same for type. And before return statement you need to free allocated memory, e.g. free(out->value); free(out->type); free(out);

Comment: I will extend by question to capture my explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the address of a variable with [**automatic storage duration**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) in `gen_token` function. For this kind of *storage duration* in [c](/questions/tagged/c):

> The storage is allocated when the block in which the object was declared is entered and **deallocated when it is exited** by any means (goto, return, reaching the end).

**Note:** using the address you've returned from `gen_token` function is an **undefined behaviour**.

I recommend you to use the [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) technique for your example, as follows:

**token.h**

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H

struct token; /* incomplete type, but you can use pointers to it */
typedef struct token token;

/* allocates memory for 'token' and initializes it */
token* gen_token(const char* r, const char* val);
/* deallocates the specified memory */
void delete_token(token* ptr);
/* returns the value of 'type' member */
const char* get_type(token* ptr);
/* returns the value of 'value' member */
const char* get_value(token* ptr);

#endif
```

**token.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "token.h"

/* the 'struct token' is defined here in the source file */
struct token {
    const char* type;
    const char* value;
};

token *gen_token(const char* type, const char* val) {
    token* out = (token*)malloc(sizeof(token));
    out->type = type;
    out->value = val;
    return out;
}
void delete_token(token* ptr) {
    free(ptr);
}
const char* get_type(token* ptr) {
    return ptr == NULL ? "" : ptr->value;
}
const char* get_value(token* ptr) {
    return ptr == NULL ? "" : ptr->type;
}
```

In the example above the `gen_token` allocates memory for a `token` object, initializes it and returns the address of the allocated memory block. This kind of *storage duration* in [c](/questions/tagged/c) is the allocated storage duration:

> The storage is allocated and deallocated **on request**, using [dynamic memory allocation functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory).

Sample usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "token.h"

int main() {
    token* t = gen_token("line", ":");
    printf("(%s, %s)\n", get_type(t), get_value(t));
    return 0;
}
```

---

One more important thing. The following variables inside your `main` function are constant arrays with automatic storage duration:

```
const char th[] = "line", va[] = ":";
```

You can store a pointer to the first element of an array, but if do it as follows, you'll have [dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer):

```
token* create_token() {
    const char th[] = "line", va[] = ":";
    return gen_token(th, va);
} /* from this point the created 'token' object will store dangling pointers */
```